# Simplify a javascript code containing multiple entries

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, element

Can anyone help me simplify this code?

Right now, I have to add to this code whenever I upload a new entry. 
I would like it to work so that there is just one script that will identify the element IDs ("#rolly" or "#lagrimas") and run a code (.toggle('show')) on an entry depending on its state.

Also please let me know if this is better done with php. Although I would prefer javascript if that's possible...

The javascript that I add to everytime there is a new profile upload is this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery("#rolly").toggle('show');
jQuery("#lagrimas").live('click', function(lagrimas) {        
     jQuery("#rolly").toggle('show');
});

jQuery("#rodrigo").toggle('show');
jQuery("#ferber").live('click', function(ferber) {        
     jQuery("#rodrigo").toggle('show');
});

jQuery("#michael").toggle('show');
jQuery("#cruz").live('click', function(cruz) {        
     jQuery("#michael").toggle('show');
});

jQuery("#rodolfo").toggle('show');
jQuery("#paladin").live('click', function(paladin) {        
     jQuery("#rodolfo").toggle('show');
});

jQuery("#rommel").toggle('show');
jQuery("#abadiano").live('click', function(abadiano) {        
     jQuery("#rommel").toggle('show');
});
});
```

While below is an example of one of the html entries (corresponding to the first javascript above):

```
[btn_default_disabled id="lagrimas" class="btn" value="show/hide"  fomable_id=3 default='Select' disabled='Reserved']
<br>
<div id="rolly">[formidable id=3]</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use common classes and DOM traversal to make your code more DRY.

Also note that `live()` was deprecated a *long* time ago. It's even been removed from jQuery v3. I would strongly suggest you don't use it, and also look to upgrade your version of jQuery to at least 1.12.

```js
$(".btn").on('click', function() {        
  $(this).next('.target').toggle();
});
```

```css
.target { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="lagrimas" class="btn">Toggle</button>
<div id="rolly" class="target">rolly</div>

<button id="ferber" class="btn">Toggle</button>
<div id="rodrigo" class="target">rodrigo</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what do you mean by upload a new entry in the question. I'll answer your question based on guessing.

It seems like you have having a set of a div and a button associated with it.
To simplify the code, you should abstract out this relationship by using class, and then binding the jquery event using the class selector instead of using the id.

Sample as below.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.display').toggle('show');
  $('.container').on('click', '.btn', function() {
    $(this).siblings('.display').toggle('show'); 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button class="btn" id="lagrimas">Click lagrimas</button>
    <div class="display" id="rolly">
      I am Rolly.
      </div>
    </div>

<div class="container">
  <button class="btn" id="ferber">Click ferber</button>
    <div class="display" id="rodrigo">
      I am Rodrigo.
      </div>
    </div>
```